How can I change public scheme to another in QGIS
I've installed postgis extension in scheme "main" in my DB. I set
SET search_path = main, "$user", public;
I can create geometry fields in my DB and seems that the extension works well. But QGIS DB Manager v3.36.1 can't find postgis tables in my DB
SQL error: SELECT has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'SELECT'),
 has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'INSERT'),
 has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'UPDATE'), 
 has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'DELETE') returned 0 
[ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist]

I think there is some option which I have to set, but I can't find, please help

While SET search_path TO myschema,public; sets the search_path for the current session only, you can make it permanent for the user running the command:
ALTER USER username SET search_path TO myschema, public;
